# Quotient of modular group and principal congruence subgroup

Tags: modular-group

The principal congruence subgroup $\Gamma(n)$ of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ is a normal subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ with index
$$[SL(2,\mathbb Z):\Gamma(n)]=n^3\prod_{p|n}(1-\tfrac{1}{p^2}),$$
where the product is over all primes dividing $n$. The quotient group is isomorphic to $SL(2,\mathbb Z)/\Gamma(n)\cong SL(2,\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$. Is this group known to be  isomorphic to a family of basic groups, such as $S_n$, $A_n$ or $D_n$?

For $n=2$ the quotient group must be non-abelian and of order $6$, and thus isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_3$. Is it known for $n\geq 3$?

Comment: The alternating group $A_n$ is not even a quotient of $SL_2(\Bbb Z/N\Bbb Z)$ for any $N$ and any $n > 5$ (The group $SL_2(\Bbb Z/N\Bbb Z)$ is not isomorphic to such families of "basic groups". Look at the center).

Comment: Thanks. It seems from this paper https://pjm.ppu.edu/sites/default/files/papers/PJM_April2018_521to526.pdf that the quotients are isomorphic to $S_3$, $A_4$, $S_4$, $A_5$ for $n=2,3,4,5$. But this doesn't continue for $n>5$.

Comment: In that paper they consider the quotients of the modular group $\Gamma$ (and not of $SL_2(\Bbb Z/N\Bbb Z)$), if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in the quotients $SL(2,\mathbb Z)/\Gamma(n)$. Is this not what you meant?

Comment: You wrote this: "$SL(2,\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$. Is this group known to be  isomorphic to a family of basic groups, such as $S_n$, $A_n$ or $D_n$?" So I assume you want to study the group $SL(2,\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z)$ (where $N$ need not be $n$ in general). And this group is not isomorphic to $A_n,S_n,D_n$ in general.

Comment: Yes indeed. But why am I then interested in quotients of $SL(2,\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$? I was wondering if it is isomorphic to some finite group that I understand better, but even the index calculation would rule out $A_n$ or $S_n$ of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145460/discussion-between-el-rafu-and-dietrich-burde).